# Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!

Tags: mysql, debian

I restarted my VPS box ( manually/hard restart ) and ever since, mysql fails to start for whatever reason.

I did a `tail /var/log/syslog` and I get this:

```
Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]:                                                                     ) ;InnoDB: End of page dump
575 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: 110220 11:49:33  InnoDB: Page checksum 1045788239, prior-to-4.0.14-form checksum 236985105
576 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: stored checksum 1178062585, prior-to-4.0.14-form stored checksum 236985105
577 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: Page lsn 0 10651, low 4 bytes of lsn at page end 10651
578 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: Page number (if stored to page already) 3,
579 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
580 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
581 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: file read of page 3.
582 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
583 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
584 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
585 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
586 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: error.
587 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
588 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
589 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
590 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
591 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
592 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: See also InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-recovery.html
593 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
594 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld[11461]: InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
595 Feb 20 11:49:33 kyrgyznews mysqld_safe[11469]: ended
596 Feb 20 11:49:47 kyrgyznews /etc/init.d/mysql[12228]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
597 Feb 20 11:49:47 kyrgyznews /etc/init.d/mysql[12228]: ^G/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
598 Feb 20 11:49:47 kyrgyznews /etc/init.d/mysql[12228]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
599 Feb 20 11:49:47 kyrgyznews /etc/init.d/mysql[12228]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
600 Feb 20 11:49:47 kyrgyznews /etc/init.d/mysql[12228]:
601 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld_safe[13437]: started
602 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
603 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
604 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: 110220 11:49:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
605 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
606 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
607 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
608 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: buffer...
609 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
610 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: file read of page 3.
611 Feb 20 11:49:56 kyrgyznews mysqld[13440]: InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
```

I have looked at the page it referenced, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html, but before messing with any settings I was wondering what experienced DBAs would suggest doing? Is there any harm in forcing the recovery?

PS - I did not make any updates to mysql. Version is mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what is in that log I suggest you run some disk checking, as it's possible you have disk errors which are causing the corruption of the database. If the disk check out you may want to restore from your backup if you are unable to repair the database.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock exists in your server. if not exist you can create it. this tuts will help you http://anthologyoi.com/computers/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socketerror.html

Comment: `mysqld.sock` did not exist. I followed and did the `touch` and `chown` and it still fails.